# How can I migrate mysql_fetch_array to $wbpdb?

Tags: wpdb

I am migrating a script with direct MySQL access to the $wpdb class, but it fails. Below is both original and new code next to each other. What is wrong?

```
<!-- 
##############################################################################

     PART 1:   OLD MYSQL FUNCTIONS 
--> 

<?php

function get_tag_data2() { 

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT lastname, count( lastname ) AS mycount FROM `tng_people` GROUP BY lastname ORDER BY count( lastname ) DESC LIMIT 0 , 35) AS presort order by rand()"); 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $arr[$row['lastname']] = $row['mycount'];
  }   
  return $arr;  
} 
?>


<!-- 
   ##############################################################################

     PART 2:   NEW WPDB FUNCTIONS 
--> 


<?php 
    global $wpdb;

function get_tag_data2() { 

  $tngnameresults = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT lastname, count( lastname ) AS mycount FROM `tng_people` GROUP BY lastname ORDER BY count( lastname ) DESC LIMIT 0 , 10) AS presort order by rand()"); 

  $arr = array();
  foreach ($tngnameresults as $result) {
        $arr[$result->lastname] = $result->mycount; 
   }
  return $arr;  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't need to post all that code to wade through! The problem is here:

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb;


function get_tag_data2() {
```

You need to `global` *inside* the function - that's [the point of global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global):

```
<?php

function get_tag_data2() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Original function code
}
```